# How do I run a program from cpp the same way as I would do it via launch as admin in explorer?

Tags: c++, windows, uwp

I'm unpacking a executable from my UWP application and storing them in the LocalState folder. Then I launch a dedicated fullTrust utility and try to execute this program as administrator. This fails.

If and only if I launch the same exe via the explorer, by clicking on "Run as administrator" it works.
With other exe which are lying in different folders it works flawless.

The code I'm using to launch is:

```
SHELLEXECUTEINFO shExInfo;
ZeroMemory(&shExInfo, sizeof(shExInfo));

shExInfo.cbSize = sizeof(shExInfo); // structure size
shExInfo.fMask = mask;              // execution flags
shExInfo.lpVerb = _T("runas");      // run elevated
shExInfo.lpFile = szExe;            // application to start    
shExInfo.lpParameters = params;     // some params
shExInfo.lpDirectory = nullptr;     // current working directory
shExInfo.nShow = show;              // show/hide the application

ShellExecuteEx(&shExInfo)           // This returns false, thus meaning a failure to start the exe
```

Why is it failing if I launch it as administrator from my cpp, but not from explorer. And how do I solve this problem?

Comment: Can UWP applications run elevated apps?

Comment: Yes via the fullTrustProcessLauncher it works, you can specify one app which will be launched by UPW, from that on you have a win32 application with all freedoms.

Launching a win32 exe as admin works in general, but not in this specific folder, when the file is created by the UWP application.

Comment: This is a "download malware and p0wn the machine" scenario.  FullTrustProcessLauncher is limited to invoking a properly installed app by its app-id.

Comment: Not actually, you can launch an EXE that is included in the UWP package, this exe can then do anything they can do as a win32 exe

Comment: @supermar10 No you cannot use api call to launch EXE in a UWP package. The desktopbridge support way is to put it in the manifest. So in UWP the API way is only LaunchUriAsync, not launch exe.

Comment: @BarryWang-MSFT I can launch a win32 exe via the ```FullTrustProcessLauncher.LaunchFullTrustProcessForCurrentAppAsync(groupId)``` it has to be defined the manifest before but it works, are we talking about different things?

Comment: We are talking about the same thing. I thought you were trying to call a exe directly. But obviously you've found the right track to do this. Glad to see that.

Comment: Ah ok :) thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my code works the way I expected it, the problem was that it was parsing the path incorrectly, thus failing to launch it.